# Android: AsyncTask OR normal Java threads with ExecutorService

Tags: java, android, multithreading

My application uses a `Service` to do some background stuff. I am using additional threads in the service to do some computation. For this purpose I create two threads every 5 to 10 seconds, which are running 5 to 10 seconds. But I don't know which thread-model I should use:

1. AsyncTask:

   Pros:

   - easy to use
   - android specific
   - easy UI-interaction

   Cons:

   - Since I have to use API level 10, there is no `ExecutorService` with fixed thread pool to execute the AsyncTasks
2. Normal Java Threads:

   Pros:

   - ExecutorService with fixed thread pool

   Cons:

   - Not so easy to handle, e.g. UI-interaction

Which model is better to use? Especially in concern of performance. Is there a heavy overhead when i am using AsyncTasks, and is the ExecutorService faster in reusing the threads than Android in creating new AsyncTasks?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you look at the implementation of `AsyncTask`, you will see that it uses its own thread pool using "normal Java threads".

> Is there a heavy overhead when i am using AsyncTasks, and is the ExecutorService faster in reusing the threads than Android in creating new AsyncTasks?

There should be no substantial difference between the two.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using Needle; an open-source, simple and powerful multithreading library for Android. With it you can say things like:

```
Needle.onMainThread().execute(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // e.g. change one of the views
    }
});
```

or

```
Needle.onBackgroundThread().execute(new UiRelatedTask<Integer>() {
    @Override
    protected Integer doWork() {
        int result = 1+2;
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    protected void thenDoUiRelatedWork(Integer result) {
        mSomeTextView.setText("result: " + result);
    }
});
```

Pros

- very simple API
- fixed thread pool size
- customizable thread pool size
- supports UI interaction ("do work and then use result on UI thread")
- android 1.5+
- behaves the same on all platform versions

Cons

- extra library dependency

Check it out on GitHub: https://github.com/ZsoltSafrany/needle

Comment: This looks promising. Will give it a try on my next project.