# AysncTask vs ExecutorService?

Tags: android, multithreading, service

I have to download files from a server and these files may be around 100 MBs in size. Previously i used the download manager to download these files but ended up encountering plenty of bugs and having to write complex code to track the status of the downloads. So i decided to write the download code myself and did the downloading in an `AsyncTask` (This async task won't be running in a `service` however). The `AsyncTask` seems to be working fine and i manage to display a notification in track the progress of the download.
The developer website however says this

> If you need to keep threads running for long periods of time, it is highly recommended you use the various APIs provided by the java.util.concurrent package such as Executor, ThreadPoolExecutor and FutureTask.

Can any one tell me what exactly could go wrong with an AsyncTask with a long running download in the background and why the developer website recommends an Executor service? Also is it ok to run an AsyncTask without a `service` (its currently what i am doing now)?

Comment: have you check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6557499/android-asynctask-or-normal-java-threads-with-executorservice and this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7717334/asynctask-v-s-threadpoolexecutor-for-network-request

Answer (score 2):

The main difference is,

- `AsyncTask` is a **class** with single threaded Executor (by default), which allows you to perform background operation and posts the results on UI thread. It acts as a helper class for Thread and Handler, allowing us to manipulate threads and/or handlers.
- `ExecutorService` on the other hand is an **`interface`** which extends the `Executor` interface. It defines a contract and its up-to the underlying implementation to decide how the execution shall take place and manage the Threads accordingly.

  Android also provide some abstract default implementation in form of [AbstractExecutorService](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/AbstractExecutorService). Most commonly used concrete implementation is [ThreadPoolExecutor](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor):

  > Thread pools address two different problems: they usually provide
  >   improved performance when executing large numbers of asynchronous
  >   tasks, due to reduced per-task invocation overhead, and they provide a
  >   means of bounding and managing the resources, including threads,
  >   consumed when executing a collection of tasks. Each ThreadPoolExecutor
  >   also maintains some basic statistics, such as the number of completed
  >   tasks.

Answer (score 1):

A potential problem with `AsyncTask` is that it uses a single threaded executor by default. If you don't provide your own executor, your long running task will prevent any other `AsyncTask` from using the default executor.

Regardless of whether you use an `AsyncTask` or an `Executor`, you need to host it in an Android component that will survive until the task is finished. If you expect your task to reliably run when your app is not in the foreground, it needs to be in a `Service`, and ideally a foreground service. Otherwise it will only run for about a half hour at most (on recent versions of Android) before the process is killed.

Answer (score 0):

I think the AsyncTask will normally work (if you don`t really it close (destroy activity)). You can use IntentService to download independently your data even, when your app is really closed. Also you need to add the premissions to your manifest for independent services (or just create it using new -> service ...).
Also, Async Task works in its own thread.